# MySQL Select - Order By using a Preferred Value

Tags: mysql

I have the following Select Statement:

```
SELECT user,color FROM accounts LIMIT 100;
```

The 'color' value has around 150 different values.

Is it possible to return all values but preference one.

So say - yellow is preference - could I get yellow at the top and then the rest returned after in one Query?

thanks

Comment: check my answer, with a simple if you can make this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a sorting id.

Something like that:

```
SELECT user, color, WHEN color = 'YELLOW' then 1 else 2 end as SortingId FROM accounts LIMIT 100 ORDER BY SortingId;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT color, IF(color='yellow',1,2) AS top FROM colors ORDER BY top ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT user,color
FROM accounts
WHERE color LIKE '%yellow%'
LIMIT 100)
UNION
(SELECT user,color
FROM accounts
WHERE color NOT LIKE '%yellow%'
LIMIT 100)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would think the easiest is something like:

```
ORDER BY count(color);
```

This way always the most popular color should be on top.